# How do I change hostname on Android? (and reachable by a ping?)

Tags: android, hostname

I need to change the hostname of my tablet in my Android Application. The idea is to make the call "ping my-tablet" work correctly. To accomplish this I have given the following commands (programmatically) through ADB to the tablet:

```
su
setprop net.hostname <new_hostname>
```

When I give:

```
getprop net.hostname
```

However, the change is not notified to the network... so if I ping the device, nothing happends.

I've seen this resource: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html but I'm not sure if it solves the problem.

There are also other solutions (like editing manually the host file, although I should do it for every connected device... or changing directly the router that is not something I can do every time) but they seem not feasible.

Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: You need to set up a DNS server or WINS, to allow other computers to resolve that hostname.

Comment: the problem is that this is a product that we have to sell worldwide... with no idea of the networks where it will be used. So I imagine that's not something that we can do using only from the tablet.. right?

Comment: Yes, you can't do that.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a hostname based solution.  Instead look at http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Comment: I should be able to connect via browser to the tablet using the hostname. I don't know if that solution is what I need, it seems more like a service to make two devices communicate over the network.. or am I wrong?

Comment: "I  should be able to connect via browser to the tablet using the hostname." You need to either revise your requirement, or accept that it will require support from infrastructure on the local network.